# read multiple files, but figure out which file I am currently on

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to use this syntax:

sc.textFile(','.join(files))

However I also need to match each line to the corresponding text file and save it to db later on.  Is there a way to append the file name to rdd or somehow know which file I am currently reading?  at the end I want a df with a string (file line contents) and another string (corresponding file name).

Comment: You probably want to provide a more complete code snippet so we have some context

Comment: What's `rdd` and `df`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution, hoping it will help someone.
I am reading a directory with jsonl files.  What I get back is a dataframe where the first column is the value of the line, and the second column is the file name where this line comes from:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
.......
read_files = spark.sparkContext.textFile(some_dir_with_files)
lines = read_files.map(lambda x: x.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
json_data = lines.map(lambda line: json.loads(str(line)))
df = spark.createDataFrame(json_data, StringType())
df_with_file_names = df.withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())
return df_with_file_names
```